# join/awk: Join 2 files on a column

Tags: bash, join, awk

I want to join below 2 files on 2nd column.

```
# cat vmid
10   win7-x64-17   [datastore1]   win7-kms-17/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
11   win7-x64-18   [datastore1]   win7-kms-18/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
4   win7-x64-11   [datastore1]   win7-kms-11/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
5   win7-x64-12   [datastore1]   win7-kms-12/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
6   win7-x64-13   [datastore1]   win7-kms-13/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
7   win7-x64-14   [datastore1]   win7-kms-14/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
8   win7-x64-15   [datastore1]   win7-kms-15/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08
9   win7-x64-16   [datastore1]   win7-kms-16/win7-template_1.vmx   windows7_64Guest   vmx-08

# cat mac
00:0c:29:2f:00:d8   win7-kms-11
00:0c:29:db:f1:15   win7-kms-12
00:0c:29:ca:a3:d3   win7-kms-13
00:0c:29:f1:5e:ef   win7-kms-14
00:0c:29:1a:55:a6   win7-kms-15
00:0c:29:77:2e:93   win7-kms-16
00:0c:29:ae:5f:7f   win7-kms-17
00:0c:29:20:b4:aa   win7-kms-18
```

Expected Output (be it unsorted, no worries):

```
10  win7-x64-17     00:0c:29:ae:5f:7f
11  win7-x64-18     00:0c:29:20:b4:aa
4  win7-x64-11      00:0c:29:2f:00:d8
5  win7-x64-12      00:0c:29:db:f1:15
6  win7-x64-13      00:0c:29:ca:a3:d3
7  win7-x64-14      00:0c:29:f1:5e:ef
8  win7-x64-15      00:0c:29:1a:55:a6
9  win7-x64-16      00:0c:29:77:2e:93
```

And below are my 2 tries. **Both return nothing**:

```
# awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1;next } ($2 in a) {print $2" "a[$2]" "$1 }' vmid mac
# join -j 2 <(sort -k 2 vmid) <(sort -k 2 mac)
```

I know that my commands are working fine because when I try it on a test input, both above commands worked as expected as below:

```
# cat f1
82  d   
83  r
10  k
12  s

# cat f2
m   r
b   d
p   k
p   s

# join -j 2 <(sort -k 2 f1) <(sort -k 2 f2)
d 82  b
k 10 p
r 83 m
s 12 p

# awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1;next } ($2 in a) {print $2" "a[$2]" "$1 }' f1 f2 
r 83 m
d 82 b
k 10 p
s 12 p
```

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If the commands return nothing, it could be that one file is empty. Perhaps your files aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Heh, actually the 2nd columns do not match. That explains empty output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `join` you can use the following command:

```
join -1 4 -2 2 <(tr '/' ' ' <vmid | sort -k4) <(sort -k2 mac) | cut -d' ' -f1,2,8
```

Explanation:

`join -1 4 -2 2` joins the input files based on column `4` of the first input file and column `2` of the second input file.

However, `join` expects the files to be sorted by that columns to work as expected. Also we need to separate `win7-kms-1` from `win7-kms-1/win7-template_1.vmx` meaning replacing the `/` by a space in order to present it as a separate column to `join`. You might prepare the files regarding this before calling `join` but you also can use [*process substitution*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (as I showed).

At the end I'm using `cut` to select only the columns of interest.

---

So far to the `join` command. I wanted to explain that. An alternative to solve your use case would be to use `awk` as you already mentioned. Actually I would suggest that.

You was almost there, but it should be:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]/]+' 'NR==FNR{s[$4]=$1;next}$2 in s{print s[$2],$2,$1}' vmid mac
```

I'm using *one or more* space or `/` characters to delimit fields. This makes it simple to access `win7-kms-1` in field `$4`.

`NR == FNR` is true as long as the total line number equals the line number in the current file. Actually this is only true as long as we read the first input file. We use that to create a lookup table from `vmid` and store field one based on field four.

`$2 in s{print s[$2],$2,$1}` checks then for the lines of `mac` if they appear in the lookup and prints the values of interest in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. +1. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually it's up to you, and I would usually not ask this, but hey!, why do you accept a fragile `awk` implementation without a single word of explanation instead of a proper crafted answer that explains everything you wanted to know?

Comment: Other awk solution came 1st in chronological order. Later I saw awk solution appended in your post. I enjoyed your join solution, but I accepted the other awk answer which was earlier in time. Anyway, I will accept yours as your comment made me think that it deserves the green click for the explanation. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. IMHO it was right to do so. I was busy to explain the `join` stuff and then went on explaining an `awk` solution. That's why the other `awk` solution came first. I had it in mind from when I started to answer but wanted explain both `join` and `awk`. At the end, also keep in mind it is not a race. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk(assuming the words are always kms and x64):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sub("kms","x64",$2);a[$2]=$1;next}{print $1 ,$2,a[$2];}' mac vmid
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (in perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

my %mac_lookup;

while ( <> ) {
   my @fields = split; 
   if ( $fields[0] =~ m/^\d{2}:/ ) { 
       $mac_lookup{$fields[1]} = $fields[0]
   }
   else {
       my ( $key ) = $fields[3] =~ m,([\w\-]+)/,;
       print join "\t", @fields[0,1], $mac_lookup{$key},"\n";
   }
}
```

This will work when supplied your file names on command line or via stdin.

- iterate line by line
- if it starts with `\d{2}:` assume it's a mac->host pair, and insert into `%mac_lookup`
- Otherwise assume it's a data line
- extract key from the 4th field (arrays start at 0 in perl)
- use that key to read from the hash.

Giving:

```
10  win7-x64-17 00:0c:29:ae:5f:7f   
11  win7-x64-18 00:0c:29:20:b4:aa   
4   win7-x64-11 00:0c:29:2f:00:d8   
5   win7-x64-12 00:0c:29:db:f1:15   
6   win7-x64-13 00:0c:29:ca:a3:d3   
7   win7-x64-14 00:0c:29:f1:5e:ef   
8   win7-x64-15 00:0c:29:1a:55:a6   
9   win7-x64-16 00:0c:29:77:2e:93
```

Note - order will match file order, not sorted.

This will collapse to a one liner if desired (although IMO that's generally not a good thing - you get hard to read results).

```
perl -lane 'if($F[0] =~ m/^\d{2}:/){$M{$F[1]}=$F[0]}else{print join "\t", @F[0,1], $M{$F[3]=~s|/.*||r},"\n"}'
```